# API Level error

Tags: android

In an Activity I have a code that shows this error, but only if you press save.

```
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.SearchView#setSearchableInfo
```

If I change the android:minSdkVersion to 7, it works, but when I save the code again, the same error is thrown. The minSdk must then be changed back to 8,...
What is wrong?

Comment: You can't use that method in API 8. You need at least API 11.

Answer (score 4):

`SearchView` is available since API lvl 11.

Since your minimum sdk is 8 (lower than 11), Lint will give an error when using `SearchView`.
You can remove that error by using `@TargetApi` annotation before your method or class.
But you have to make sure you use a conditional statement before using `SearchView` to check if it is available, and provide an alternative for earlier versions.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
void yourMethod(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        // use SearchView
    } else {
        // use some other backward compatible custom view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The SearchView exists in Android from the version 11 ant more.
So, if you would like to use the SearchView in your code, you have to put the minSdkVersion in your manifest to be 11. In the case you put a number smaller than 11, you will get an error, which is normal beause you are giving access to your app to some android versions which will not support your app.

This can be seen (thanks to @JesseJ) here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

```
Added in API level 11
```

Comment: As seen here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: You don't *have* to change the minSdkVersion to 11, but you'd definitely need to add in conditional logic to check the device's API level at runtime and only call that function if the device is running API 11+.